# XMPPFramework for Objective-C. How to implement such setphoto method

Tags: objective-c, methods, xmppframework

```
/**
 * When XMPPvCardAvatarModule is included in the framework, the roster will integrate    with it.
 * Implement this method to provide support for storing the downloaded user photos.
**/
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
- (void)setPhoto:(UIImage *)image forUserWithJID:(XMPPJID *)jid xmppStream:(XMPPStream    *)stream;
#else
- (void)setPhoto:(NSImage *)image forUserWithJID:(XMPPJID *)jid xmppStream:(XMPPStream    *)stream;
#endif
```

In XMPPFramework i have such comment that tells me to implement some method to store the users photo. How should I implement this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it. I haven't vCard, therefore i can't upload photo.

If vCard will be avaliable this method works fine.